# retrofit forcing ui to freeze

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

I recently started using retrofit libraries.. long story short, my UI is getting frozen, until all retrofit calls are completed..

point to be noted  **in the place of retrofit if you are using async task then the UI has no problem there is no freezing..**

i tried calling the retrofit methods in do in background no change...
also tried calling it in a thread.. no change..

between the ui contains a custom progress bar, which should be continuously running..

so how to remove the lag?? 
retrofit code

```
 public static ApiClientInterface mainUrl() {
    if (apiClientInterface == null) {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(
                "http://projects.quinoid.com").build();
        // common.php?&status=
        apiClientInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiClientInterface.class);
    }

public interface ApiClientInterface {

    @GET("/LTFoods/json/common.php")
    void getCategories(@Query("status") String status,
            @Query("viewset") String viewset,
            @Query("currentdate") String date,
            Callback<CategoriesModel> callback);
```

}

this is the final code.. using threads ..

```
 private void threads(String date, String login,
        Context activityContext){

    final String currentDate = date;
    final String loginOne = login;
    final Context activityContexT = activityContext;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            URL_Retrofit.Categories(currentDate, activityContexT, false);
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            URL_Retrofit.Directors(activityContexT, currentDate);
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            URL_Retrofit.CorporateAddress(activityContexT, currentDate);
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            URL_Retrofit.DistributorDetails(activityContexT, loginOne,
                    currentDate);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: retrofit makes request on separate  thread why are you using a thread for retrofit request

Comment: @PramodYadav my ui is lagging.. i did not have this issue with async task..  thats why i tried running on a seperate thread...

Comment: then you are executing retrofit wrong way

Comment: @PramodYadav i tried it without thread.. same result.. and i checked the code.. i dont know what i am doing wrong.. could u help me?? the code is above